# JQUERY - how do I validate/check my check-boxes/radios in my code structure?

Tags: jquery, validation, checkbox, radio-button

I am making this far worse and more difficult than it has to be, but I can't figure this out.

I need some custom validation coding for a special client app we are working, **so can't use jquery val plugin**

All I want is a checkbox and radio validation function built basically the same as I have for the textfield validation.  My code for the checkbox and radio validation is so bad it broke the originally working textfield validation

I have stripped the non working code disaster that I had - could some please show me how to work this?

Using the code structure in my jsfiddle/below: when you click the "btnCatchReqFlds" button I want it to run the text field check and then the checkbox, radio check and display all of those field that are required, but not filled-in/checked/selected.

Look at the **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/justmelat/mPXAw/)** and you will see how it works with just the textfield validation.  I just need to incorporate the same functionality/check with checkboxes/radio buttons.

**I think I am close, well closer.  I have updated the code and I know this is not great coding, but taking it in baby steps to get what I need.  The code below now checks for required but empty text and check/radio fields.  The problem now is, the code grabs the correct fields, but the ".not(':checked');" is not working properly.  If I check one of the radios/checkboxes, I get the same return value**.  What am I doing wrong with this: **`return $(this).not(':checked');`**

**[my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/justmelat/mPXAw/):**

**jquery:**

```
$("#btnCatchReqFlds").on('click', function()  
{
    $("#holdErrMsg").empty();
    $("#holdErrMsg_checkRadios").empty();
    var requiredButEmpty = $("fieldset:visible").find('input[class*="-required"], select[class*="-required"]').filter(function() 
            {
                return $.trim($(this).val()) === "";  
            });
    var chk_requiredButEmpty = $("fieldset:visible").find(":input:checkbox[class*='-required'],:input:radio[class*='-required']").filter(function()
            {
                return $(this).not(':checked');
            });
    if (requiredButEmpty.length) 
        {
            requiredButEmpty.each(function () 
                {
                    $("#holdErrMsg").append("Please fill in the " + this.name + "<br />");
                });
        }
    if (chk_requiredButEmpty.length) 
    {
        chk_requiredButEmpty.each(function () 
            {
                $("#holdErrMsg_checkRadios").append("Please fill in the " + this.name + "<br />");
            });
    }
    return !requiredButEmpty.length;
    return !chk_requiredButEmpty.length;
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <div id="holdErrMsg"></div>
    <div id="holdErrMsg_checkRadios"></div>
    <fieldset id="mainSection" name="mainSection">
        <legend style="color:blue; font-weight:bold">Project Overview Section</legend>
        <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 33px; width: 178px;">Name<span style="color: red">*</span></td>
                <td style="height: 33px"><input id="1125" name="1125" class="1125-required" type="text" /> - 1125</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 33px; width: 178px;">Email<span style="color: red">*</span></td>
                <td style="height: 33px"><input id="1026" name="1026" class="1026-required" type="text" /> - 1126</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 178px">Product Title</td>
                <td><input id="1089" name="1089" type="text" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 178px">Product Type</td>
                <td>
                    <select id="1169" name="1169">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                        <option value="Cars">Cars</option>
                        <option value="Boats">Boats</option>
                        <option value="Planes">Planes</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button id="btnCatchReqFlds" type="button" name="btn">Check Required Fields</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
    <!-- Car Section  -->
    <fieldset id="section-11" name="section-11">
        <legend style="color:fuchsia; font-weight:bold">Car Details Section</legend>
        <table cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 334px; height: 35px"><label>Size:<span style="color: red">*</span></label></td>
                <td style="height: 35px"><input id="1245" class="1245-required" name="1245" type="text" /> - 1245</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 35px; width: 334px">Color:<span style="color: red">*</span></td>
                <td style="height: 35px">
                    <select id="1433" class="1433-required" name="1433">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                        <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
                        <option value="Blank">Blank</option>
                        <option value="Green">Green</option>
                    </select>
                    - 1433
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 334px">Description:</td>
                <td>
                    <textarea id="1290" name="1290" rows="2" style="width: 433px"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
    <!-- Plane Section  -->
    <fieldset id="section-12" name="section-12">
        <legend style="color:fuchsia; font-weight:bold">Plane Details Section</legend>
        <table cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 334px; height: 35px"><label>Size:</label></td>
                <td style="height: 35px"><input id="1245" name="1245" type="text" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 35px; width: 334px">Color<span style="color: red">*</span>:</td>
                <td style="height: 35px">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="1433[]" id="1433[]" value"Orange" class="1433[]-required" />Orange
                    <input type="checkbox" name="1433[]" id="1433[]" value"Blue" class="1433[]-required" />Blue
                    <input type="checkbox" name="1433[]" id="1433[]" value"Green" class="1433[]-required" />Green
                    |  1302
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 334px">Description:</td>
                <td>
                    <textarea id="1290" name="1290" rows="2" style="width: 433px"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
    <!-- Boat Section  -->
    <fieldset id="section-13" name="section-13">
        <legend style="color:fuchsia; font-weight:bold">Boat Details Section</legend>
        <table cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 334px; height: 35px"><label>Size:</label></td>
                <td style="height: 35px"><input id="1245" name="1245" type="text" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 35px; width: 334px">Color:<span style="color: red">*</span></td>
                <td style="height: 35px">
                    <input type="radio" name="1834" id="1834" value="None" class="valuetext 1834-required" />None
                    <input type="radio" name="1834" id="1834" value="All" class="valuetext 1834-required" />All
                    - 1834
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 334px">Description:</td>
                <td>
                    <textarea id="1290" name="1290" rows="2" style="width: 433px"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
    <br />
    <!-- Misc. Info Section  -->
    <fieldset id="section-1011" name="section-1011">
        <legend style="color:green; font-weight:bold">Misc. Info Section</legend>
        <table cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 334px; height: 35px"><label>Size:</label></td>
                <td style="height: 35px"><input id="1301" name="1301" type="text" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 35px; width: 334px">Color:</td>
                <td style="height: 35px">
                    <select id="1302" name="1302">
                        <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
                        <option value="Blank">Blank</option>
                        <option value="Green">Green</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 334px">Description:</td>
                <td>
                    <textarea id="1303" name="1303" rows="2" style="width: 433px"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't see any radio buttons or checkboxes in the fiddle

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have mentioned that you need to use the product type drop down.

Answer (score 0):

With your recent update all you need to do is check if all siblings are checked or not then grab one out of the array of elements it returns back to your variable.  If you insert the code below before you start appending the error messages it should work the way you want.  Heres an updated fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/mPXAw/7/

```
var chk_requiredButEmpty = $("fieldset:visible").find(":checkbox[class*='-required'],:radio[class*='-required']").filter(function()
{
       if(!$(this).siblings().is(':checked')){
               return !$(this).is(':checked');
       }
});
chk_requiredButEmpty = chk_requiredButEmpty.eq(0);
```

Comment: Hi wirey, thanks so much for trying.  I wonder if there is something with the original code.  The issue, this is a sample app, so there could be 3 product types or 50.  There could be 20 sections with 200 required fields, so the code has be more dynamic.

Comment: The reason why it won't work with the original code is because you right now you have text boxes where you can compare if the value is an empty string.  Here you can't since the are either checked or not unless you make a hidden field which holds the value then check that hidden field.

Comment: Wirey - I think this actually works.  THANK YOu.  You have no idea how long I have been fighting with this.  THANK YOU!!!!!!

Comment: @user1176783 Oh you came back to look at my updated answer :P  I'm glad to help

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong with this: **`return $(this).not(':checked');`**

You're assuming the `.not` is the inverse of `.is`, which is not the case. [`.not`](http://api.jquery.com/not) does *not* return a boolean value, it returns a jQuery object containing elements that do not match the selector.

You should simply use:

```
!$(this).is(":checked")
```

to determine if something is not checked. Or even better:

```
!this.checked
```

**Updated fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/VSx6M/

---

Some other notes:

- You have two `return` statements at the end of your event handler. The second one is unreachable because `return` returns program flow back to the calling function immediately.
- Array literal (`[]`) notation is preferred over `new Array`.
- Radio buttons are being validated multiple times because you are not taking radio button groups into account. This causes radio buttons to be flagged as invalid because they are all marked required.

<sup>*I know you can't use jQuery validate, but I would highly recommend trying to.</sup>